# How to use OnClickListener on Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I am developing a simple Android Application with 2 tabs.
I have implemented the Tabs very well.

Tab1 consists of Fragment 1
Tab2 consists of Fragment 2

Now i want to add a button in Fragment 1, and when the user clicks on that button, some activity is displayed.

I have tried the following code, and it is not working.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        // Locate the viewpager in activity_main.xml
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**FragmentTab1.java**

```
package com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml

        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);


    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(view == getView().findViewById(R.id.button1))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }

}
```

**fragmenttab1.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/Fragment1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Click Me"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The app crashes on load.
As i am very new to Android Dev, **PLEASE EXPLAIN IN DETAIL THE PROBLEM THAT IS CAUSING THIS AND THE RIGHT SOLUTION**

Thanks.

The Logs are:

```
03-03 20:43:23.514  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial E/dalvikvm﹕ dvmPauseGc(AppLaunch) called - cookie=0xc069 (f=0x1)
03-03 20:43:23.519  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
03-03 20:43:23.529  15010-15028/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:18 height:18 bitmap id is 180
03-03 20:43:23.529  15010-15026/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 181
03-03 20:43:23.529  15010-15029/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:18 height:18 bitmap id is 182
03-03 20:43:23.529  15010-15024/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:48 height:48 bitmap id is 183
03-03 20:43:23.529  15010-15027/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:18 height:18 bitmap id is 184
03-03 20:43:23.529  15010-15025/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:42 height:126 bitmap id is 185
03-03 20:43:23.529  15010-15030/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 186
03-03 20:43:23.529  15010-15023/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 187
03-03 20:43:23.564  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
03-03 20:43:23.564  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11345: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
03-03 20:43:23.564  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-03 20:43:23.564  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
03-03 20:43:23.564  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11351: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
03-03 20:43:23.564  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-03 20:43:23.564  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
03-03 20:43:23.564  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9039: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
03-03 20:43:23.564  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
03-03 20:43:23.569  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-03 20:43:23.569  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 364: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-03 20:43:23.569  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-03 20:43:23.569  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-03 20:43:23.569  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 386: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-03 20:43:23.569  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-03 20:43:23.579  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 188
03-03 20:43:23.614  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-03 20:43:23.614  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41acec08)
03-03 20:43:23.619  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial, PID: 15010
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial.FragmentTab1.onCreateView(FragmentTab1.java:17)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2532)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2262)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1391)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1590)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 20:43:25.609  15010-15010/com.adhish.pagertabstriptutorial I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15010 SIG: 9
```

Comment: could you post the stack trace?

Comment: button does not belong to activity layout

Comment: @Raghunandan So what is the solution?

Comment: @AdhishThite the below post should help

Comment: @TommyTopas Logs posted

Comment: @AdhishThite let's try my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have issue in `onCreateView` method. You have to find button from view which you inflated, change it to :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
    v.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Yes at least the app is not crashing now. But when i click on the button, the Toast is not displayed. :(

Comment: Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Yes. I will be able to mark it as an answer in 5 minutes. I will. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you So please accept my solution if it was help for you :)

Comment: The app is working fine. But i have a different question now. When i run the Code Analysis, it shows that there's a probable bug : 'Method invocation getView().findViewById(R.id.button1) at line 30 may produce java.lang.NullPointerException' . Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: The method findViewById() has anntation that it can returns null but in this case it is not possible